Remote-SSH VS Code won't use local server despite settings ("remote.SSH.localServerDownload": "always")
I'm experiencing a frustrating issue with the Remote-SSH extension of Visual Studio Code. Here's my situation:
I'm trying to connect to a remote server via SSH using VS Code (with the Remote-SSH extension). My remote server does not have internet access, so it cannot automatically download the VS Code server.
To work around this, I've already set the following parameter in my settings.json file:
"remote.SSH.localServerDownload": "always"

I've also manually downloaded the VS Code server on my local machine (which has internet access) and transferred it to my remote server via SCP. I extracted the files into ~/.vscode-server/ on the remote server.
Despite all this, VS Code still displays "Downloading VS Code server..." when I try to connect, and it seems to completely ignore the parameter I configured to force the use of the local server.
What I’ve Tried

I've double-checked the path of the transferred files to ensure they are correctly placed in the ~/.vscode-server/ directory.

I restarted VS Code and the SSH service on the server.

I deleted the ~/.vscode-server folder and repeated the file transfer and extraction process.


What I Expected
I expected VS Code to detect the server files that I had previously installed locally and connect without attempting to download anything.
What Actually Happens
VS Code continues to attempt downloading the VS Code server despite the configuration and the locally present files. I don't understand why the remote.SSH.localServerDownload parameter doesn’t seem to work as intended.
If anyone has encountered this issue before or has any suggestions on how to fix it, I’d really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance.

Can this help : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/9330 ?
